androidTest (instrumented): How to click the ALLOW button on Android 8.0 (API 26)?
For an instrumented androidTest test, I need to click the ALLOW "button" as popped up by the system when the app starts on a device running Android 8 (API 26):

(Note: on Android 14 (API 34) I have no problem as the permission dialog box is entirely different and its "allow/grant" button can be accessed by its resource id)
The following code:
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
            dialogContainer = device.findObject(By.textEndsWith("to record audio?")); // Android 8.x
            if (dialogContainer != null) {
                UiObject2 allowButton = dialogContainer.findObject(By.textStartsWith("Allow"));
                if (allowButton != null)
                    allowButton.click();
                 else
                    logE("PermissionTest", "Error! Could not find 'Allow' dialog button");
            }
            else
                logE("PermissionTest", "Error! Permission dialog did not appear");


results in:
09-13 10:52:09.831 30108 30133 W UiObject2: Clicking on non-clickable object:
 android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@64c49;
 boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 756, 175);
 boundsInScreen: Rect(412, 1083 - 1168, 1258);
 packageName: com.google.android.packageinstaller;
 className: android.widget.TextView;
 text: Allow My App to record audio?; error: null;
 maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null;
 viewIdResName: com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_message;
 checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: false; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false;
 longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false;
 scrollable: false; importantForAccessibility: true;
 actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN - null]

I am suspecting this is because ALLOW is not a real button. This is because dialogContainer isn't null and allowButton isn't null either.
However, I don't know how to click that ALLOW (text? link?) programmatically from my androidTest.
What is the proper way of clicking the ALLOW button on Android 8.0 (API 26) androidTest ?

The By.textStartsWith("Allow") is finding the TextView since it has the Allow word in it - hence the click error (the error dump indicates it is a TextView) - the button has ALLOW - is the By.text.. case insensitive?

@Computable Good observation. If I replace Allow with ALLOW, then allowButton is null. So the search is case sensitive but counterintuitive because the text found isn't the text displayed.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

This answer shows how to get with res id : the res id for the allow button is com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button based on this.   Also, using the layout inspector at the time of permission display may provide more insight into the elements involved.  Not able to test so just a suggestion.

UiObject2 allowButton2 = device.findObject(By.res("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")); did the trick and it works perfectly. Please post your comment as an answer and I will make it the accepted answer. Thank you

@Computable The above statement (that works) is simply a replacement for UiObject2 allowButton = dialogContainer.findObject(By.textStartsWith("Allow")); in the code snippet in my original posting.

Based on two SO answers it was speculated and confirmed by OP that finding the "permission allow button" can be done using its android id as in:
UiObject2 allowButton2 = device.findObject(By.res("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"));

The notion of searching on resource id was found here (although plenty of other possible sources).
The actual identification of the system button resource id was found here.
As to how one could find out that id using official android documentation is a mystery at the moment - other than using SO.

Updating the original OP code:
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        dialogContainer = device.findObject(By.textEndsWith("to record audio?")); // Android 8.x
        if (dialogContainer != null) {
            UiObject2 allowButton2 = device.findObject(By.res("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button"));
            if (allowButton != null)
                allowButton.click();
             else
                logE("PermissionTest", "Error! Could not find 'Allow' dialog button");
        }
        else
            logE("PermissionTest", "Error! Permission dialog did not appear");


Note starting at API 30 (Android 11) the permission dialog has three buttons described here the additional button is the "Only this time" choice.

The beauty of your answer is that it provides a systematic approach to finding a resource id of such system level button/text, albeit Android Device Monitor application is deprecated now. Thank you
